# How to implement overwriting in my current "Redo" function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overwrite, turtle-graphics, redo

I have (along with the help of my buddy @Nuclearman who answered one of my other questions) partly implemented a redo function in my program, which is a turtle graphics program that draws any letter pressed on the keyboard pressed by the user onto the turtle graphics canvas. I say "partly" because although it does redo, it does not do what it was meant for, which is overwrite the last undone letter with a new one if one is called by the user. For example, suppose you wrote "HELLO" on the canvas and undid up to "H". You then wanted to replace the "E", with, lets say, an "A". So you draw an "A". When you press redo, it is supposed to now show "HAL" right? Well, that is not the case with my redo. My redo instead, following the example I gave, outputs this:

[image: WTH...]

It draws the E over the A! Well, that is not what the redo is meant for! So, how could I make so that the turtle would draw "HAL" instead of whatever is happening in the image above and implement this **based on my current redo function *shown below***? Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

My Redo function:

```
def Clear():
    # Clear the canvas
    clear()
    speed(0)
    tracer(0,0)

def redoHandler():
    if undoHandler.handling == True and draw.drawing == True and len(newerdeq) > 0:
        # "newerdeq" is my 'forward' stack for the redo to be possible
        redoHandler.handling = True
        if not hasattr(redoHandler, "counter"):
            redoHandler.counter = 0
        redoHandler.counter += 1
        draw.counter += 1
        print("`draw` has been called {} times.".format(draw.counter))
        Clear()
        ui = newerdeq.pop() #<-- Pop redone items...
        function.append(ui) #<-- back to the "undo" function stack.
        penup()
        try:
            goto(o,p)
        except:
            goto(-200, 100)
        pendown()

        try:
            # Now execute all the items (from an earlier queue that all letter functions go to first) if defined as a Point class or as a function
            for i in function:
            k = i.getXY()
            penup()
            goto(k)
            pendown()
            hk = i.getletterheight()
            global letter_height
            letter_height = hk
            rk = i.getletterwidth()
            global letter_width
            letter_width = rk
            hw = i.getwidth()
            width(hw)
            op = i.getcolor()
            try:
                color(op)
            except:
                for g in colors:
                    cp = g.getcolor2()
                    colormode(255)
                    color(cp)
            j = i.getfunction()
            j()
        except:
            i()



    update()
```

Comment: The case is, when you undid to H, the next pending redo-action is E, which is suppose to be. When you enter A, the redo-action is still not changed. I think what you want is when you enter a letter, you need delete the up-pending action, the next redo-action will be H. That means, when you enter a letter, call newerdeq.pop()

Comment: @xfx Well, it was as simple as that. It's fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it. It was a very simple fix. All I had to do was in the queue that each letter is executed, just put:

```
if len(newerdeq) > 0:
    newerdeq.pop()
```

Like this:

```
def draw(x):
draw.drawing = True
if not hasattr(draw, 'counter'):
     draw.counter = 0
global drawing
q.put(x)
process = False
drawingLock.acquire()
if not drawing:
    process = True
    drawing = True
drawingLock.release()
if process:
    if not q.empty():
        v = xcor()
        y = ycor()
        c = pencolor()
        w = width()
        ph = letter_height
        pw = letter_width
        x()
        po = Point(v,y,c,w,isdown(),x,ph,pw)
        function.append(po)
        if len(newerdeq) > 0:
           newerdeq.pop() #<-- Here it is... fixed.
        draw.counter += 1
        print("`draw` has been called {} times.".format(draw.counter))
        if x == draw_W:
            draw_W.drawing = True
            draw_W.counter += 1
            draw.counter -= 1
        elif x == draw_Y:
            draw_Y.drawing = True
            draw_Y.counter += 1
            draw.counter -= 1
        global h
        h = (x) 
    drawingLock.acquire()
    drawing = False
    drawingLock.release()
```